# Select Option Remove Month From Current Year

Tags: jquery

I have 3 select boxes with date month and year. If I select current year I want the previous months to be removed from month select box. If I select next year or other years it should display all months. I checked many ways but not working properly.

How can I remove all the indexes or months which are expired in current year and show back all the months if I select other years.

```
<select name="date">
<option value="0">Day</option>
<option value="2">1</option>
<option value="3">1</option>
<option value="4">1</option>
..
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="month">
<option value="0">Month</option>
<option value="jan">January</option>
<option value="feb">February</option>
<option value="mar">March</option>
..
<option value="dec">December</option>
</select>

<select name="year">
<option value="0">Year</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
...
<option value="2030">2030</option>
</select>
```

My logic now is like this.

```
$(".year").on('change', function() {
   //get the current year
   if selected year is current year -> I got this right
   then remove expired months -> This is not working right 
   if selected year is others -> Selected month should remain there
   then show all the months 
});
```

Comment: Show us html code mate

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
<select name="month">
<option value="-1">Month</option>
<option value="0">January</option>
<option value="1">February</option>
<option value="2">March</option>
..
<option value="11">December</option>
</select>

$(".year").on('change', function() {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   if($(this).val()== currentDate.getFullYear()){
      $("select [name=month] option:lt("+ currentDate.getMonth()  +")").prop("disabled", true);   
   }
   else{
      $("select [name=month] option").prop("disabled", false);    
   }

});
```

Hope it helps !!